# How to scrape email address out of a string?

Tags: excel, vba, dom, web-scraping

How do I get the email address from this html snippet?

As there are thousand of leads like this in a certain webpage and the text within it is not always found as it is seen here.

The only common thing is the email address located in the first position.

How can I get the email address and ignore the rest?

These are the elements:

```
<div class="gm_popup"><div class="gm_name">Adel Outfitters</div><div class="gm_address">1221 W 4th St</div><div class="gm_location">Adel, Georgia 31620<div style="display:none" class="w3-address-country">United States</div></div><div class="gm_phone"><span class="gm_phone_label">P:</span> 229-896-7105</div><div class="gm_email">adeloutfitters@yahoo.com<div><div class="gm_website"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/adel-outfitters/132735763434461" target="_blank">https://www.facebook.com/pages/Adel-Outfitters/132735763434461</a></div><br><a target="_blank" class="directions-link" href="http://maps.google.com/?saddr=+&amp;daddr=1221+W 4th St, Adel, Georgia, 31620">Directions<span class="w3-arrow">different stuffs</span></a></div></div></div>
```

What I tried:

```
Set post = html.getElementsByClassName("gm_email")(0)
MsgBox post.innerText
```

The result:

```
adeloutfitters@yahoo.com
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Adel-Outfitters/132735763434461

Directionsdifferent stuffs
```

Expected output:

```
adeloutfitters@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing `</div>` tag is further down which is why you are getting the extra text. Can you chop off anything after a new line? Or check each word in the string and save the one with "@" in it? Bad way of going about it, but it would probably work...

Comment: In other languages there are options to `decompose` or `drop` unnecessary tags (as in `a` tag in this case) within a certain class or tag. I'm new in vba so I don't have any idea if there is any such option here to do so. However, I thought about the idea you suggested here but can't make it a go either, I meant the technique.

Comment: Try a function like this: 

Public Function GetTextBefore(sIn As String, sFind As String) As String
Dim lResult As Long

lResult = InStr(1, sIn, sFind)

GetTextBefore = Left$(sIn, lResult - 1)
End Function


Set post = GetTextBefore(html.getElementsByClassName("gm_email")(0),vbnewline)


If that doesn't work, try using chr(10) or chr(13) instead of vbNewLine in the function I've provided.

Comment: The problem is clearly solved with this `MsgBox Split(post.innerText, vbNewLine)(0)` expression. As it came to my mind to see your suggested code, i accept it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Good scheme, I forgot about the Split function! Thanks.

Comment: Just thinking about this one some more - if you can edit the HTML before it gets interpreted, you could replace:
 <div><div class="gm_website"> with </div><div><div class="gm_website">  
and also replace 
</span></a></div></div></div> with </span></a></div></div>. 

That should make html.getElementsByClassName("gm_email")(0) be interpreted as just the email.